# Disable text anti-aliasing in Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, antialiasing

Since Qt does its own text rendering, is it possible to disable anti-aliasing for a Qt app at runtime, without changing the global OS settings?

If possible, I assume it would be done by tweaking the app's QStyle or something similar. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [QFont](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html) class exposes a [setStyleStrategy()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html#setStyleStrategy) method that allows you to alter the font matching algorithm.

Passing [QFont::NoAntialias](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfont.html#StyleStrategy-enum) should achieve what you want:

```
yourFont.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias);
```